# SQL Parameter Prompt

Tags: sql, vba

I'm trying to run a SQL command in VBA to delete certain records from a table.  When I run it I'm prompted for parameters. What is causing this? I have included the subroutine that includes the SQL.

```
Public Sub AddCon(newCont, svID)
    Dim daDb As DAO.Database
    Dim rst1 As Recordset
    Dim rst2 As Recordset

    Dim selContract As String

    Set daDb = CurrentDb
    Set rst1 = daDb.OpenRecordset("tblContracts")
    Set rst2 = daDb.OpenRecordset("tblContractList")
  
     rst2.AddNew
     rst2!Contract = newCont
     rst2!ID = svID
     rst2.Update
     rst2.Close

    Set rst2 = Nothing
    DoCmd.Close

    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "DELETE * FROM [tblContractList] " _
    & "WHERE rst1.Contract <> newCont"
 
     DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
    
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmContracts"

 End Sub
```

Comment: Your sql query is just text, so it will try to run whatever that is, you are not using any values from your above code.  You are saying just delete where rst1.Contract  but what is that?  I think you are trying to use a value from above but you are not because it is just trying to execute exactly what is between your double quotes.

Comment: `"WHERE rst1.Contract <> " & newCont` -add single quotes around `newCont` if the field is not numeric

Answer (score 1):

As you make query,

```
DELETE * FROM [tblContractList] WHERE rst1.Contract <> newCont;
```

Microsoft Access engine will ask for you two unknowns via prompt: rst1.Contract and newCont.

So you should replace them with known values:

```
Public Sub AddCon(newCont, svID)
    Dim daDb As DAO.Database
        'Dim rst1 As Recordset
        Dim rst2 As Recordset
    
        ' Dim selContract As String
    
        Set daDb = CurrentDb
        'Set rst1 = daDb.OpenRecordset("tblContracts")
        Set rst2 = daDb.OpenRecordset("tblContractList")
      
         rst2.AddNew
         rst2!Contract = newCont
         rst2!ID = svID
         rst2.Update
         rst2.Close

        Set rst2 = Nothing
        'DoCmd.Close
    
        Dim strSQL As String

        '
        ' DELETE query must be run with care, as useful data may disappear!!!
        '
        strSQL = "DELETE * FROM tblContractList " _
            & "WHERE (Contract " & " <> " & newCont & ")"
        '
        ' or single quoting newCont if it is a string:
        '
        'strSQL = "DELETE * FROM tblContractList " _
        '    & "WHERE (Contract " & " <> '" & newCont & "')"
        '

         'rst1.Close
         'Set rst1 = Nothing

         Set daDb = Nothing

         DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL


        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmContracts"

End Sub
```